# Beamforming antenna beamwidth/frequency relation

Tags: communication, wireless

What's the relation between the minimum beamwidth and frequency of a beamforming antenna (such as a MIMO transmitter)? I'd guess they'd have to be on the same order?
$$ \lambda \propto BeamWidth \text{ ?}$$

Comment: It's not my area, but isn't beam width measured in degrees or radians rather than meters?

Comment: I think OP meant "related to", or "proportional to".  Not necessarily that the units are the same.

Comment: @SteveSh I doubt that; \$\approx\$ is not \$\propto\$, and something being in the same order (I guess of magnitude) is also not a description of proportionality.

Comment: (unless you describe under which units something is in the same order of magnitude, how would that work?)

Answer (score 3):

> What's the relation

There is none. *Beamwidth* is an angle (i.e., unitless quantity), and the *wavelength* is a length (i.e., a unit-stricken quantity)¹.

You can, for **a few specific** design of antennas relate the *ratio of some dimension of the antenna to the wavelength* (which, because it's a ratio of lengths, is unitless again) to the beamwidth². This works mostly for high-gain antenna designs with "simple" shapes, such as parabolic dish antennas ("satellite dishes") and large linear arrays of dipoles (as you'll find e.g. on SAR earth observation satellites), because the largest dimension (diameter, maximum length) dominates the gain of the antenna, and the rest will be designed to give maximum gain anyway by any reasonably competent antenna designer.

**However**, you mention MIMO systems. These can form any beam pattern that they have enough degrees of freedom for, so there's no fixed beam width at all, and that makes it "doubly impossible" that such a relationship exists.

---

¹  This might indicate you have confused beamwidth for a length – which would probably mean you need to go back and revisit antenna basics!

²  Which you, by the way, also have to define. It's not inherently clear what that is, because physically, radiation patterns cannot have jumps, so it's always a problem of setting some limit to what you call "beam".

Comment: "There is none" - relationship between beamwidth and wavelength.  That's not quite true.  For a fixed size aperture, the beamwidth is proportional to the wavelength. ; the smaller the wavelength (higher the frequency) the narrower the beam.

Comment: @SteveSh pretty much what I described in the next paragraph :)

Comment: There is probably a relationship like, for a given maximum antenna (or array) diameter, there is a minimum achievable beam diameter. Where the diameter of an irregular shape is the longest distance between two points in the shape.

Comment: @ThePhoton indeed, the effective area of an aperture antenna cannot be larger than its physical area – and the shape maximizing area under fixed maximum dimension is the circle. And that's where the parabolic dish comes in ;)